# updating one model from another

Tags: knockout.js

I have two models of the same type, model *A* and model *B*. I want to update model *A* with the properties of model *B*. Both models are bound to different areas of the UI.

Is there a way to do the update without having to go property by property?

```
// address = model A
// this.editingBillingAddress() = model B

var address = ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.userAddresses(), function (address) {
    return address.addressId() == 123;
});

//address = this.editingBillingAddress(); // this does nothing. nothing in the UI updates

// this works but I must explicitly set every property
address.name(this.editingBillingAddress().name());
address.address1(this.editingBillingAddress().address1());
address.address2(this.editingBillingAddress().address2());
// .... and so on until the fingers bleed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in the second comment of this question: [Updating Knockout.js Observable array element value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11246815/550073).

```
var address = ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.userAddresses(), function (address) {
    return address.addressId() == 123;
});

this.userAddresses.replace(address, this.editingBillingAddress());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mapping plugin to first convert to javascript object and then map to an object with observables: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

```
var jsAddress = ko.mapping.toJS(self.address());
var address = ko.mapping.fromJS(jsAddress);
self.editingBillingAddress(address);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wk7dr/6/

Comment: Instead of self.address() you would just use address.